# How to check if an array has an element at the specified index?

Tags: php

I know there is array_key_exists() but after reading the documentation I'm not really sure if it fits for this case:

I have an $array and an $index. Now I want to access the $array, but don't know if it has an index matching $index. I'm not talking about an associative array, but an plain boring normal numerically indexed array.

Is there an safe way to figure out if I would really access an $array element with the given $index (which is an integer!)?

PHP may not care if I access an array with an index out of bounds and maybe just returns NULL or so, but I don't want to even attempt to code dirty, so I *want* to check if the array has the key, or not ;-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use either the language construct [`isset`](http://php.net/isset), or the function [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists) : numeric or string key doesn't matter : it's still an associative array, for PHP.

`isset` should be a bit faster *(as it's not a function)*, but will return `false` if the element exists and has the value `NULL`.

For example, considering this array :

```
$a = array(
    123 => 'glop', 
    456 => null, 
);
```

And those three tests, relying on `isset` :

```
var_dump(isset($a[123]));
var_dump(isset($a[456]));
var_dump(isset($a[789]));
```

You'll get this kind of output :

```
boolean true
boolean false
boolean false
```

Because :

- in the first case, the element exists, and is not `null`
- in the second, the element exists, but is `null`
- and, in the third, the element doesn't exist

On the other hand, using `array_key_exists` like in this portion of code :

```
var_dump(array_key_exists(123, $a));
var_dump(array_key_exists(456, $a));
var_dump(array_key_exists(789, $a));
```

You'll get this output :

```
boolean true
boolean true
boolean false
```

Because :

- in the two first cases, the element exists -- even if it's `null` in the second case
- and, in the third, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 8):

You can easily use `isset()`:

```
if (isset($array[$index])) {
   // array index $index exists
}
```

And as you have suggested, PHP is not very kind if you try to access a non-existent index, so it is crucial that you check that you are within bounds when dealing with accessing specific array indexes.

If you decide to use `array_key_exists()`, please note that there is a subtle difference:

> isset() does not return TRUE for array
>   keys that correspond to a NULL value,
>   while array_key_exists() does.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what the `array_key_exists` is for. It works on both numerical and string indexes.